# Why only push to a branch?

Tags: git, push, branch

If we have three branches:

- master
- develop
- feature

Where **develop** is used for CI, and **feature** is always branched from **master**...

What reason could one have for only ever merging **feature** into **develop** without merging **develop** into **feature** first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple. Normally your development branch can contain many features to test. So if you make a new feature branch from your dev branch and merge 
then the feature branch into your master you have all your features that you don't want to have online, merged into your production system.

So don't merge dev into master and make a feature branch only from master.

https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows

here is a good tutorial for a better understanding. And i hope i understood your problem correctly.

Comment: So, feature branches will not be deleted after being signed off by testers but actually get merged directly into master - rather than develop being merged into master. Correct? (I've not used that particular flavour before.) What about conflicts which occur when merging into develop?

Comment: Yes you make a feature branch from Master... if you make a hotfix merge them back to master and dev or merge them only into dev and test your features first. In some cases you make a staging branch where you merge your feature first... make a tag and merge the tag every month into master. There are a lot of possibilities.